# Get selected values of all RadioButtonLists inside a ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, radiobuttonlist, ascx

I have a ListView to create several RadioButtonList, then I want to get the selected values from each RadioButtonList after a button click.

```
    <asp:ListView ID="lvForm" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li>
                <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Texto") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="<%$ Resources:liSim.Text %>" Value="<%$ Resources:liSim.Text %>" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="<%$ Resources:liNao.Text %>" Value="<%$ Resources:liNao.Text %>" />
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemSeparatorTemplate />
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <ol style="list-style-type: upper-alpha;">
                <li id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
            </ol>
        </LayoutTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSeguinte" Text="<%$ Resources:btnSeguinte.Text %>" OnClick="btnSeguinte_Click" />
```

The best solution was to do OnSelectedIndexChanged on each RadioButtonList and keep saving after each change. But this workaround forces to go server-side at each change.

How can I collect all selected values only after a button click?

Comment: javascript is your best friend

Comment: Where and what is this button you are clicking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to simply iterate each item in the ListView. First, name your RadioButtonList in your ListView. It will make it easier to find.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbList" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="<%$ Resources:liSim.Text %>" Value="<%$ Resources:liSim.Text %>" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="<%$ Resources:liNao.Text %>" Value="<%$ Resources:liNao.Text %>" />
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Then loop each item. Find the RadioButtonList in each item. Get the SelectedValue of the RadioButtonList you just found and use it however you'd like.

```
protected void btnSeguinte_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> selectedValues = new List<string>();
    foreach(ListViewItem item in lvForm.Items)
    {
        RadioButtonList rb = (RadioButtonList)item.FindControl("rbList");

        // if none are selected, it returns an empty string
        if(rb.SelectedValue.length > 0)
        {
            selectedValues.Add(rb.SelectedValue);
        }
    }

    // do something with your selected values

}
```